# Bash: move identically named files in sibling directories to new directory structure

Tags: android, bash

I want to run this command over and over again in a loop (rather than doing it 73 times by hand):

```
mv values-bg/x_strings.xml ~/workspace/myapp/app/res/values-bg/
```

The only thing that will change with each iteration is the suffix after `values-`. It will be `af`, `ar`, `az`, `be`, `bg`.... It'll also sometimes look like `values-es-rES`.

The directories contain other files I don't want to move, so I can't just copy the whole directory structure. I want to pluck just this one file from each directory.

Context: I have a translation service which translates a `x_strings.xml` file from English to dozens of languages. Now that those strings are translated, I need to move them into the correct directories. I'd love to automate this. Thanks!

**Update:**

I ended up doing this, which basically worked:

```
for d in `find . -type d`; do mv "${d#./}"/x_strings.xml ~/workspace/myapp/app/res/"${d#./}"/; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for d in `find . -type d`; do mv "${d#./}"/x_strings.xml ~/workspace/myapp/app/res/"${d#./}"/; done
```

This can be run directly from the command line. The `find` command finds all directories in the current directory and allows me to iterate over them in the `for`. `"${d#./}"` strips off leading `./` from the directories provided by `find`.

One caveat here is that this won't move files into non-existent directories, but that is exactly the behavior I wanted.